# Cannot add a view to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just deployed an app to Heroku, its URL is: http://msitproject.heroku.com

When I uploaded the app it was working fine but then I added another view named `developer`.
This link is working perfectly in my localhost but when I click on Developer link in the navbar on Heroku I get redirected to the error 500 page. I can't figure out that why is this happening.

I used the code

```
git push heroku master
```

followed by:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

The link of my github repo is: https://github.com/rohitbegani/msitproject

Here are my heroku logs:

```
2014-02-05T18:26:29.028106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/user_friendships.json host=msitproject.herokuapp.com request_id=5e6692bd-8d4d-40dc-863b-2ec608bebe70 fwd="122.161.19.141" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21ms status=401 bytes=61
2014-02-05T18:26:31.981378+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/developer" for 122.161.19.141 at 2014-02-05 18:26:31 +0000
2014-02-05T18:26:31.985163+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeveloperController#show as HTML
2014-02-05T18:26:32.022137+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered developer/show.html.erb within layouts/application (34.6ms)
2014-02-05T18:26:32.022137+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (rohitbegani.jpg isn't precompiled):
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div class="dev-image offset5"><%= image_tag 'rohitbegani.jpg' %></div>
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <h1 class="dev-text">Rohit Begani</h1>
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/developer/show.html.erb:1:in ``_app_views_developer_show_html_erb__2217822362271118091_28442460'
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <h3 class="dev-text">Developer, Designer and an avid football fan</h3>
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <p class="dev-text">Hi I am a developer and a designer from New Delhi, India. Some of the languages I code in are Ruby, RoR, HTML, CSS(3).<br> I am a strong believer of open source and most of my projects are available publicly.<br>Other than coding I love to watch football and root for the gunners. Oh yeah I love bikes.<br> I am the co-founder of ObtuseOrange, a design comapny based in New Delhi, India</p>
2014-02-05T18:26:32.024083+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-05T18:26:32.028671+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/developer host=msitproject.herokuapp.com request_id=fc9de369-7b14-49bf-ae60-3cec6082e2a8 fwd="122.161.19.141" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=48ms status=500 bytes=64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to precompile your assets locally and then push it again on heroku

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

after compilation don't forget to do

```
$git add public/assets
$git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

in your master branch, this way u  will be pushing your latest master with compiled assests,

Comment: I have added the content in heroku logs to the question

Comment: here is the prob ActionView::Template::Error (rohitbegani.jpg isn't precompiled)

Comment: try to push your code on heroku once again, if again it show same error then, compile your assets locally using this command
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile , after compilation is done then push it again.

Comment: @RahulSingh Your answer currently doesn't attempt to actually answer the question. You should use a comment instead to ask for more information. Please either edit your answer with your most recent comment (and an actual resolution) or create a wholly new answer and delete this one.